# Use a CSS-variable in SVG via <img>

Tags: html, css, svg, css-variables

I have an SVG which I currently display via an `<img src="foobar.svg">`. The parent HTML has some CSS associated which defines variables which I need in the SVG. The SVG has a `<style>` to hotlink this.

The CSS-variables defined in the parent seem to not be available to the SVG. Is there some way to make it work? I can't just copy the CSS; I could, as last resort, inline the SVG into the HTML.

The current setup is something to the tune of

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="the_css_that_defines_the_variables.css">
</head>
<body>
<img src="foobar.svg">
...
```

---

```
<svg>
<style type="text/css">svg { fill: var(--myvariable) }</style>
...
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables cannot be transferred from one document to another. Within a single HTML document, variables can be declared in the inline `style` attribute of individual elements, but that's about as far as you can go.

If the variable must be a CSS variable, you'll need to inline that SVG for it to be able to use it.